Hardware interrupt for PC from GPIO signal
I'm looking for a fast method to synchronize between a GPIO signal (3.3V TTL) and a Python program.
Currently, I'm using an Arduino with the following setup:
The Arduino (Arduino Uno) works in 2MHz Baud rate

Sends a pulse to Oscilloscope Channel 1.
Sends a single uint8 character over Serial.
Waits for Serial data from the PC.
Sends another pulse to Oscilloscope Channel 2.

The PC (Python):

Waits for Serial data.
Sends a single uint8 character back over Serial.

I've measured around 5ms between the two pulses, which is too long for my needs. My goal is to reduce this delay to less than 100µs.
I'm open to suggestions regarding alternative modules, cables, PC hardware, or any other improvements that could help achieve this.

How fast are you running your serial port? It takes almost 100 us to send one character one way at 115,200 bps. Also, if you want that kind of real-time response from a PC, you need to be running something other than Windows on it.

What Dave said, also why do you want ti use a PC

Why can't the response be done from the Arduino itself? As Dave said, real-time response from a (probably) massive multi-processor, multi-tasking system is not likely to give good results, and usually takes a lot of work (removing layers, like Python itself, OS overhead, increased rights like running as root, or installing as a driver, etc.). Whereas on the Arduino this can be done within microseconds.

Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Hi
The Arduino is Arduino Uno, with 2MHz Baud rate.
The whole system is much more complicated, and I need to use a computer for it. I thought about switching to Linux, but I dont know how significant it will be.

@דרוראיזיק - the higher baudrate helps (somewhat), but if you're sticking with the 100µs real-time target, then you cannot realistically involve a PC.

ok, Thank you.
I need to think this through.

So how is your Arduino connected to PC - my guess is via USB?

I think i should write the whole peoblem, but I will do it in another thread. Thank you everyone.

As already stated in the comments, one character at 115,200 baud 8N1 (you've not specified) is ~86.8µs... so assuming a perfect zero-time response (i.e: no processing at all, not even just entering an interrupt routine and sending a fixed character back) you're looking at ~173.6µs, and you've already blown your 100µs target.
Can you remove Python and the PC from this loop? The scheduler alone is going to introduce significant jitter in the round-trip time at this scale, so I'd expect your measured "~5ms" be more like "5ms best-case, 150ms+ wors case depending on system activity / load".
Note also that your 100µs target is only 1,600 clock cycles for the Arduino (presumed to be an AVR running at 16 MHz - again, you've not specified)... entering interrupts consumes cycles, and many AVR instructions take more than one cycle to complete... realistically, you're looking at the Arduino itself executing very few instructions in a carefully crafted ISR to get anywhere near your (maybe impossible) 100µs target.
For context, the tick of the Linux scheduler is generally between 1-10ms, and the Windows scheduler ticks at around 1-15ms (ref).

It seems the presumption of AVR @ 16 MHz was correct, and you've indicated the baudrate is 2 Mbaud (presumably 8N1).
This means that for one character in each direction, you'll consume ~10µs just to transfer the message back and forth... this is now a <80µs time limit for whatever remote processing you're trying to do - a general purpose PC will not be able to achieve this.

You are wanting a 100us response time and that is simply impossible with the Arduino and PC in the loop.
Why? USB.
The Arduino communicates with the PC over USB.
USB has a polling rate of 1ms. There is no way you can get below 2ms because the PC (OS, drivers, USB host controller) needs to poll every 1ms if there is data and when data is seen then it can be passed on to your software to which your software can respond and at earliest the next chance to send an USB packet is 1ms later.
For that matter, the implementation of how your Arduino board converts USB traffic into UART traffic for the Mega328P.
And since it uses 2 Mbps with the USB chipset, it takes 5 microseconds just to transfer a byte, so after Mega328P sends a byte, it arrives 5 microseconds later to USB interface chip for buffering and sending to PC. And also when USB interface chip receives a data packet from PC, and after buffering starts to send a byte, it arrives 5 microseconds later back to Mega328P.
The 100us requirement leaves 90 microseconds for the USB chip, PC, and your software.
Consider actually getting 5ms as extremely good. It is unlikely you can get any better performance than that and should also not expect any better.
In order to improve on anything, you need to first and foremost get rid of USB. Use a computer and Arduino with direct UART connection between them without USB. In order to have a computer with real UART it might mean it's not a PC anymore, but maybe some other computing device - such as Raspberry Pi or Jetson or other ARM device with built-in UARTs.
But if you switch to something like that, you can also skip the Arduino and byte transmitted over UART and use the GPIO and interrupt pins of the CPU directly. I bet it might be doable on Raspberry Pi in Python but still routing a pin change interrupt to a Python program and toggling another GPIO pin from there in 100us would likely be pushing it.

The rule of thumb I use is this:
PC with regular OS: 5-20ms (also non deterministic)
PC with RTOS and GPIO: 10us to 1ms
General hardware timers on micro: 20ns (50MHz after that you need impedance control)
FPGA's: ns timing or as good as the clock
So what do you need?
You'll need something with hardware timers, they do have libraries that can run python on microcontrollers, but your best bet is some kind of C language with a micro.

at 115200 bps  a single uint 8 talks 10 bit times so to send (assuming 8n1 line discipline)
your best possible response time is thus 20 bit times.  or just under 180us
Be sure to set the receive interrupt threshold to 1 at both ends else the receive interrupt will be delayed
Your best bet for fast interrupts on a PC is probably DOS and and ISA bus, but to get a UART faster than 115200 on that it probalby means PC108 and you'll also be needing to level convert between 5v and 3.3v.  And I'm guessing this is probably somewhere you don't actually want to go.

In Windows a time slice (time a process is allowed to run) is up to 20 ms.
This means that there can be large amount of jitter when you want to send and answer back from user space.
So, getting 5ms is already really good!
The only way to decrease the latency and jitter is by using kernel space, as a driver. It is impossible to use an interpreted language such as python for this.
Windows drivers must be C++.
Some parallel or serial port pci cards still have an IRQ on some pins, you may be able to write a C++ application for this (in userland) to minimize the latency.

"It is impossible to use an interpreted language such as python for this." You are obviously not familiar with the recent "crowdstrike" exploit in Windows, in which an interpreter inside a Windows driver was induced to dereference a null pointer by a bad configuration file, rendering the affected system unbootable.

@DaveTweed that is not a standard windows feature, but if you want to first make a kernel space interpreter, sure go ahead. It went well for them.
